# openCV: keypoint allocation issue in dll file

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, visual-studio-2005

I had developed a simple code in openCV:

```
void extractSIFT(Mat img, Mat outFeature, int G = GRID_SPACING)
{
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    DenseFeatureDetector denseDetect = DenseFeatureDetector(PATCH_SIZE,1,0.1,G);
    denseDetect.detect(img,keypoints);

    SiftFeatureDetector siftDetector(SIFT_DIM,NUM_LAYER,CONTRAST,EDGE_THRESHOLD,SIFT_SIGMA);
    siftDetector.compute(img,keypoints,outFeature);
    outFeature.convertTo(outFeature, CV_32FC1); //Convert to float

}
```

which works perfectly well in a VS2010 c++ program. However, when I make it into a dll file and then call it from a VS2005 program I get the following error on the line

```
denseDetect.detect(img,keypoints);
```

which is

> Expression: vector iterators incompatible

When I look to the variables in debug session I cannot see anything in keypoints variable. Nothing, not even size is 0 thing, not a line. When I query keypoints.size() it says 'keypoints.size() does not exist'

[image: an 'empty' vector of KeyPoints] (you can see the small blank area under keypoints)

The memory address exists in program memory area but the first 4 bytes are 0x00 which looks strange:
[image]

I tried using different visual studio runtimes (vc90, vc 80, vc100 cannot be called from vs2005), debug and release configurations and numerous other things which I cannot recall now but in the end, it doesn't work.

I suspect from the allocator of KeyPoint class but I couldn't find any workaround for it except 'It works in linux installation with release configuration' which is not an option.

We have a working webservice running on VS2005 so it is expected to work on these platform.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit: We have migrated the project to VS2010 C# with .NET framework 4 and the problem has resolved.**

Answer (score 0):

Never use multiple *VStudio C Runtime Lib*s (*msvcr##(#).dll*) or their *C++* counterparts (*msvcp##(#)*.dll), in your program (one in the main *.exe* and another in a *.dll* loaded by that *.exe*) unless you're very familiar with the implications (could get lots of *Access Violations* at runtime).

In order to get this working (since the executable can't be changed) you should build the *.dll* using *VStudio 2005* (note that its redistributables are assemblies, so you should use the exact same one that the webservice uses).

Or, the natural thing to do: migrate to a newer *VStudio* version.

Comment: Cannot build the dll in VS2005, built the webservice in VS2010 instead.

Comment: So how does the VS2010 built dll work with the VS2010 built executable?